# What does it mean for the cross product to be invariant under orthogonal transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

[This article](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math132/crossproducts.pdf) claims $Ax \times Ay = \det(A)(x\times y)$, but using the vectors $(3,2,1)$ and $(5,4,6)$ and the orthogonal transformation with determinant $1$:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$$
does not hold.

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
3 \\
2 \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-2*\sqrt{3}+3}{2} \\
\frac{3*\sqrt{3}+2}{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
5 \\
4 \\
6
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-4*\sqrt{3}+5}{2} \\
\frac{5*\sqrt{3}+4}{2} \\
6
\end{matrix}\right)$$

and 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-2*\sqrt{3}+3}{2} \\
\frac{3*\sqrt{3}+2}{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)\times \left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-4*\sqrt{3}+5}{2} \\
\frac{5*\sqrt{3}+4}{2} \\
6
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{13*\sqrt{3}+8}{2} \\
\frac{8*\sqrt{3}-13}{2} \\
2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

but $(3,2,1)\times (5,4,6)=(8,-13,2)$.

**So, what does it mean for the cross product to be invariant under orthogonal transformation?**

Comment: The claim in the linked note is obviously wrong. I think it is correct if you multiply the cross-product on the right by A.

Comment: You say "this article" : first of all, it is not an article, it is a page page written by anybody anywhere in the Realm of nowhere... It is not because something is written that it is true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v=(3,2,1)$ and $w=(5,4,6)$, then, indeed $v\times w=(8,-13,2)$. And$$A.(v\times w)=\left(4+\frac{13\sqrt{3}}2,4\sqrt{3}-\frac{13}2,2\right).$$It turns out that\begin{align}(Av)\times(Aw)&=\left(\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{3},1+\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2},1\right)\times\left(\frac{5}{2}-2 \sqrt{3},2+\frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{2},6\right)\\&=\left(4+\frac{13\sqrt{3}}2,4\sqrt{3}-\frac{13}2,2\right).\end{align}As you can see, $(Av)\times(Aw)=\det(A).A(v\times w)$ in this case. Actually, it's true for every orthogonal matrix $A$.

Comment: Any hints on how to prove this fact that $Av \times Aw=\det(A)A(v\times w)$ when $A$ is orthogonal?

Comment: You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/666759/446262).